# SQL - Five most recent completed training courses for each user

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I've looked on this site and seen people use Top 5 and Limit but both throw errors for me. 
Basically, I want to see the five most recently completed (statuscodename='Attended') courses [Course Date] for each user [Foster Parent]. Below is the code I currently use to get every course completed in the last three years which is what I'm trying to modify.

```
SELECT Family.name AS Family, 
         FosterParent.fullname AS [Foster Parent], 
         TrainingSchedule.btb_schedule AS [Training Course], 
         TrainingSchedule.btb_coursedate AS [Course Date] 
FROM     dbo.FilteredBtB_trainingrecord TrainingRecord
         LEFT OUTER JOIN FilteredAccount Family ON TrainingRecord.btb_familyid=Family.accountid, 
         dbo.FilteredBtB_trainingschedule TrainingSchedule, 
         dbo.FilteredBtB_trainingcourse TrainingCourse, 
         dbo.FilteredContact FosterParent 
WHERE    TrainingSchedule.btb_trainingscheduleid=TrainingRecord.btb_trainingscheduleid 
AND      TrainingSchedule.btb_courseid=TrainingCourse.btb_trainingcourseid 
AND      FosterParent.contactid=TrainingRecord.btb_fosterparentid 
AND      Family.statuscode = 1 
AND      TrainingRecord.statuscodename = 'Attended' 
AND      (TrainingSchedule.btb_coursedate > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 36, DAY(GETDATE())-1) 
OR       TrainingSchedule.btb_coursedate > GETDATE())
ORDER BY 1,2,4
```

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit joins - it's a true mess. Switch to the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why are you choosing NOT to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax for all your joins?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Sorry I used an old version of Advanced Query Tool to create the code (my work don't have a licence for a more modern version)

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you know how to help me?